# Copy and re-name a file on android

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard

I have a file which I am using as a temporary file until the user selects to save this file, How do I go about making a copy of this file but at the same time re-naming it. Example below:

```
File 1:

/sdcard/Folder/file1.wav

File 2:

Copy of file 1, renamed to file2.wav in /sdcard/Folder/file2.wav
```

I understand using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` gets me the path to the external storage so i'm not asking how I get to the sdcard or whatever. just to make a copy of a file and re-name it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) [FileUtils.moveFile(File, File)](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html).